# How to find an array of numbers(elements) from array of n numbers whose sum is exactly equal (or nearly equal) to the number x.?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sum, dynamic-programming

How to find an array of numbers(elements) from array of n numbers whose sum is nearly equal or exactly equal to the number x.? 
I implemented using recursive. But it takes too much time. Pls help
Is there any algorithm?
Can it be implemented using DP? if yes How?
Eg:
`

```
given Array a = { 43, 86, 12, 39, 58, 15, 9, 62, 40, 71 }

If x = 125;
ans : {39,15,71}
Here sum of ans = 125 (exactly)

for same array:
if x = 49
ans = { 39, 9} 
Here sum of ans 48. nearly equal
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) - it's NP-Complete, but there's a pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming algorithm and a polynomial time approximate algorithm